# How to exclude CommonJS libs from production build with Webpack (vue-cli)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I have managed to do that for `vue` by using Webpack config [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)

---

First I included the CDN for Vue in my html file

**index.html**

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
```

Then I modified my webpack config

**vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    // ...
    externals: {
      vue: 'Vue',
    }
    // ...
  },
}
```

Things worked perfectly.

---

But when I tried with `vue-class-component` and `vue-property-decorator`, it didn't not worked as expected

**index.html**

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-class-component@7.2.5"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-property-decorator@9.0.0"></script>
```

**vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    // ...
    externals: {
      vue: 'Vue',
      'vue-class-component': 'VueClassComponent',
      'vue-property-decorator': 'VuePropertyDecorator',
    }
    // ...
  },
}
```

---

I noticed that the names of these files are different, end with [`.common.js`](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-class-component@7.2.5) and [`.umd.js`](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-property-decorator@9.0.0)

```
vue-class-component.common.js
vue-property-decorator.umd.js
```

Then I tried

**vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    // ...
    externals: {
      vue: 'Vue',
      'vue-class-component': 'commonjs2 vue-class-component',
      'vue-property-decorator': 'umd vue-property-decorator',
    }
    // ...
  },
}
```

But it did not work as well

Below are how I import these in my `src/`. Scripts are written in typescript

```
import Vue from 'vue'

// ...

import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
```

---

Anyone knows how to handle `externals` in webpack with `.common.js` and `.umd.js`? Many thanks!

Comment: "it didn't not worked as expected" ....what that mean exactly?

Comment: @MichalLevý sorry for not being clear enough, it means that my app crashed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think problem is necessarily in Webpack config...

If I try to load `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-class-component@7.2.5` it gives me `Original file: /npm/vue-class-component@7.2.5/dist/vue-class-component.common.js` which is CommonJS build - browser will not handle that. Try use link to a "browser compatible" build like `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-class-component@7.2.6/dist/vue-class-component.min.js`

`vue-property-decorator` should be fine as [UMD module](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-property-decorator@9.0.0/) should work in the browser...

BTW whats the point of all this? Why not let Webpack do its thing ? Its always better do download one big JS file then multiple smaller...